# AWS Lambda having Intermittent 504 (Endpoint request timed out) error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call a multipart/form-data API call from front-end to nodejs back-end and inside of this lambda function I am using Axios post form data to achieve multipart/form-data. There are also multiple DB calls as well.

Lambda function returns success for first time and next time not. Again success and then failure and it's happening continuously.

I know there are multiple post and answer related api gateway timeout 30 secs etc. In this scenario remote api returns data within 3 secs, but still this issue persist.

Kindly help me to resolve it.

Comment: Are there any Cloud Watch messages for your Lambda Function, when this happens?

Comment: Does it always return it in 3 seconds? Are you sure? Set the Lambda timeout to 5 minutes and try again to make sure

Comment: @kgiannakakis before hit the remote API, it prints all the logs, but when it goes to error, after 29 sec, it returns END RequestId: c12d9456-b4c4-4669-8064-ae4ac615bcf6

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Lambda default timeout is 30 and API gateway as well 30. So, if I increase the time of lambda, I think it doesn't help, because the gateway will return the result within 30 sec. When it success it returns within 5 secs max